# Why do we have to edit at least 6 characters?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, editing

Very recently, I clicked the edit button on a question.

It had a misspelling of just one letter.

But after I clicked the save my edit button, an error message popped up saying the edit should at least include 6 characters.

Why should we edit at least 6 characters when sometimes there is just one character that needs editing?

Comment: The official answer from the site founder is at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77257/294691

Comment: @Mithical I took a look at that question, answers and comments. The site founder has posted a biased answer. He has called single character edits trivial, without thinking about their importance in stackoverflow codes and searching questions on the sites.

Comment: @SnackExchange I'm curious - biased against whom?

Comment: @bobble Not against a person. But against a good idea.

Comment: Some single-character mistakes completely change a question or answer.  (Particularly when dealing with code, of course, but others are possible.)